# Big-O notation name for O(n^c), where c >= 4

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have an algorithm whose time complexity is `O(n^c)`, where `c ≥ 4` (and `c` is an integer).

Per the [Time Complexity's Wikipedia page's Table of common time complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities), they do not list this case.

What is the nickname for this time complexity?

Edit: I am interested in the name for keeping `c` as a variable (basically a natural number `≥ 4`), not so much a particular `c = 7` or `c = 42`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, any `n^c` for integer `c` is called a polynomial time complexity. It matches with the polynomial class of problem as well and is denoted by `P`. Here is [the time complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity)).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode exactly.

Comment: In the [Time complexity page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)'s intro, it says "an algorithm with time complexity O(n^α) for some constant α > 1 is a polynomial time algorithm."  So I believe this is indeed the correct name, even if it's not exactly reflected in the table.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#Names_of_polynomials_by_degree) lists quartic, quintic, sextic, septic for degrees 4 to 7, and says names for some higher degrees have been proposed but are rarely used.

Comment: These terms are often used by mathematicians when talking about polynomials of specific degrees (e.g. [there is no general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Finding_roots_of_a_quintic_equation) to a quintic equation using radicals), but I don't know if computer scientists would be likely to describe an algorithm as having quartic or quintic time complexity; at that point the algorithm is not efficient but it still matters for theoretical reasons that it's polynomial, so I would normally expect to see it just called "polynomial" in this context.

Comment: @kaya3 "quartic" has just been used [under an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394625/binning-a-set-into-subsets-deterministically/69394926?noredirect=1#comment122658327_69394926) I'm following :-)