# Binning a set into subsets deterministically

Tags: algorithm, set, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an unordered set of `n` unique, positive integers. I want to partition it into `ceil(n / k)` unordered sets of up to `k` numbers (`k << n`) in a deterministic way (I want to get a sequence of the same `ceil(n / k)` output sets without depending on a fixed order of the input).

Is there a way to do so that has superior algorithmic complexity to sorting the set and partitioning the resulting sequence?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I believe that the answer should depend on what the numbers are, and not on what order they arrived in.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Your many, separate, narrow questions are adding a lot of noise to this post. I think posters in the future would appreciate asking fewer, bigger questions when you don't grok a question or answer at all. It makes it harder to follow things when there are a lot of tiny question. Picking apart an answer when you don't understand the question yet is also really noisy and seldom helps a whole lot.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode The idea is that you don't care about the order of the input set or the order within each of the resulting `ceil(n / k)` output sets. Whether the input is `{1, 2, 3, 4}` or `{2, 3, 4, 1}` is irrelevant and undefined. I want to generate the same outputs every time, say if k=2 to generate e.g. `{2, 3}` and `{1, 4}`, no matter which order I consider the input in. Note that "`{3, 2}` and `{1, 4}`" is the same answer as "`{2, 3}` and `{1, 4}`" -- there is no meaning of order to a unordered set.

Comment: What is the range of the unique, positive input integers?

Comment: And what are the ranges of `n` and `k`?

Comment: @גלעדברקן the integers are 64 bits, k is order of hundreds, and n is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach whose average performance is `O(n)`, which beats `O(n log(n))`.

Pick `m` with `r < m < n`, where `r = ceil(n / k)` is the number of buckets.  For each number, hash it and stick it into one of `m` bags.  (I'm deliberately using bags vs buckets, with bags smaller.) This is a `O(n)` task.  Now we can construct our `r` buckets by running through the `m` bags, and when fill a bucket up up, we quickselect a single one of the `m` bags.  Running through those bags is `O(m)`, putting them into the `r` is `O(n)`, and splitting the `r-1` bags on a boundary with quickselect is `O(r * (n/m))` which is definitely contained within `O(n)`.

Comment: Couldn't we take m = n even? With a universal hash, you have time in expectation to insertion sort each bag.

Comment: What are you doing with the hashes?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I didn't think about that option.  Yes, we could.  However there is overhead in having lots of buckets, and then `1/e` of them would be empty.  But, say, `m = n/5` gets rid of most of that bucket overhead.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode They are used to decide which bag to assign a set entry to

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode You are splitting the set based on hash value.  That involves doing a lot of sorting it - but the fact that hashes have an even distribution lets us use a bucket sort for most of the work.

Comment: I edited your post to use the new name `r`. You were using `k` differently than I used `k`. (I specified `k << n`, but because of this `r` is actually proportional to `n`.)

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "quickselect a single one of the m bags?" I don't understand at all :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן The simple version is that we're prepending the hash token to each number, doing a bucket sort (fast on average due to the hash), and then chunking the sorted list into bins. But we don't actually need to finish the sort; we can just find the bin boundaries.

Comment: Is this worst-case here quartic? Suppose your data are all hash-colliding so you end up all in one bag. You'll have to quickselect the bag r times. Each quickselect is worst-case quadratic and the remaining size of the bag is proportional to n.

Comment: @MikeGraham Quartic in what? It's cubic in n, no?

Comment: @MikeGraham No,that's `O(r * n^2)` worst case. If you add a trivial amount of logic to recognize that a bag holds multiple buckets and recurse, then you're doing a partial quicksort and get a `O(n^2)` algorithm.  If you go complicated and use a median-of-medians you'll get a worst case `O(n log(n))` algorithm with bad constants.

Comment: So, long story short, hashing only helps if the hash algorithm actually does a good job of hashing. The widespread use of hashing is an acknowledgement that, in practice, it generally does.

Comment: @MikeGraham unless you're direly space constrained, you can take m a little larger and just sort with (e.g.) heapsort as I observed above, which will be O(n log n) with a reasonable constant.

Comment: """No,that's `O(r * n^2)` worst case."""

`r` is proportional to `n`, so you're claiming it's cubic in `n`.

I think I wasn't appreciating that quickselect is worst-case n^2, but quickselect r times is not worst case r*n^2, but rather decays to quicksort and is just worst-case n^2

Comment: """So, long story short, hashing only helps if the hash algorithm actually does a good job of hashing. The widespread use of hashing is an acknowledgement that, in practice, it generally does."""

I wasn't trying to claim that the pathological case was a typical case.

Comment: """which will be O(n log n) with a reasonable constant""" This is really easy to do in n log n -- that's what we're trying to beat, right?

Comment: @MikeGraham If this is a practical program, the average case is almost certainly more important than the worst. I already beat it.  Otherwise the best that I can do is a modified quick-select with median-of-medians to give a worst case of `O(n log(r))`.  Depending on how `<<` `r << n` is, that might count as an improvement.

Comment: `r` isn't `<< n`. `r` is almost as big as `n` because `k << n`

Comment: @MikeGraham Oops, I meant `k`.  Sorry.  The point being that you're only doing a quicksort to `log(k)` levels.

Comment: @MikeGraham O(n) average, O(n log n) worst since we're sorting tiny buckets on average.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thanks for explaining. If I understand correctly, as long as we're filling the bigger buckets, we don't care about the order within the bags, until we reach a bag we can only use partially, then we must quickselect the correct element to partition the bag and continue to fill the buckets.